# Access to the download window in Mozilla Firefox by javascript or imacros

Tags: javascript, download, mozilla, popupwindow, imacros

I'm writing a script on imacros and javascript. The script clicks on the buttons on the page and then the dialog box of file download selection (pdf) pops up. Who knows how to access this download window to select the type of download using imacros or javascript?
I wrote the following script. It works but it does not work correctly when downloading a file.

```
for (i=1;i<=3; i++) {
var macro; // Create a variable macro
macro = "CODE:"; // Enter the code for the macro
macro += "URL GOTO=http://www.dpd.ru/ols/order/order.do2"+"\n";// Go to the website
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:datePickup CONTENT=my date"+"\n";// Set the date
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:filter_show"+"\n";// Advanced Search
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:orderNum CONTENT=my number"+"\n"; //Set number of dispatch
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_refresh_btn"+"\n";// Show orders
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:order_list_form ATTR=NAME:orderId CONTENT=YES"+"\n"; // Select document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_dialog_btn"+"\n"; // Printing a document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_form_btn"+"\n";// Download window
macro += "TAB T=2"+"\n";// Opening the second tab
macro += "TAB T=1"+"\n";// Open the tab
macro += "TAG POS=12 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:close"+"\n"; // Close download menu
iimPlay(macro) // Run the variable
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWk3Y.jpg)

Comment: Add more details to your question. What steps do you want to perform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iMacros [ONDOWNLOAD](http://wiki.imacros.net/ONDOWNLOAD) command for handling the download. Just make sure the command appears *before* the line that triggers the download to start.

Comment: I tried this command but it does not help.
I need to download a lot of files (I'll include a list of files) and rename each file. Problem in the Mozilla Firefox browser dialog box.

Comment: Sorry, I would need to try the macro on the site myself to investigate why it is not working.